# Why does std::random_device define its copy constructor as deleted?

Tags: c++, c++11

The copy constructor for `std::random_device` is deleted, and I have no idea why.

The only note I found from the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device/random_device) is:

> 2) The copy constructor is deleted: `std::random_device` is not copyable.

There doesn't seem to be a clear reason for why it is deleted. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why `std::random_device` is not copyable is that if it were, the copied instance *may* return exactly the same numbers as the original (this is implementation defined though)!

This is because ([docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device)):

> **`std::random_device` may be implemented in terms of an implementation-defined pseudo-random number engine** if a non-deterministic source (e.g. a hardware device) is not available to the implementation. In this case each `std::random_device` object may generate the same number sequence.

Some implementations will thus implement a PRNG. PRNGs are generally implemented with a seed value (and some other state), from which the "random" numbers are generated. By copying `std::random_device`, this will copy the seed value, along any other internal state that the generator uses to generate random numbers (which is implementation defined).

You would have 2 random devices, which are deterministic because they generate the same number sequence:

```
std::random_device device1;
std::random_device device2 = device1; //For demonstration purposes only

std::uniform_int_distribution dis{ 0, 10 };

int randomNumber1 = dis(device1);
int randomNumber2 = dis(device2);
//Note that "randomNumber1 == randomNumber2"! They use exactly the same random number
//generator with the same seed value, etc. -> Same numbers are generated!
```

---

The implementation might always use the same seed values for every `std::random_device`, which would mean that the same number sequence is generated every time for different random devices. Or it might use some non-deterministic source (taken from above):

> In this case each `std::random_device` object may generate the same number sequence.
>
> ---
>
> [...] if a non-deterministic source (e.g a hardware device) [...]

In those cases it doesn't matter that the random device is copyable (one would not think that the copy is in fact a copy), but it *does* matter where the implementation generates *different* values for different random devices using a PRNG.

Implementing the copy constructor (and the copy assignment operator) would break that assumption for the implementations that use a PRNG, and so it is deleted, to maintain the "randomness" of the numbers generated for every implementation (as long as the implementation allows it).